# ios webview won't stop loading..kind of

Tags: ios, image, webview, loading

So in my web view controller pertaining to the UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked part, I have override methods.

Some pointing to urls which fire a download manager, and one part pertaining to a image view controller, in which it loads the image and allows me to save it.

It is held in a navigation controller just as my whole app is.

The first time I tap a image it loads fine, the previous view doesn't open the image as I have called [webView stopLoading]. The second time, maybe third time I tap the same image, the image loads in the same webview BUT also pushes my view controller.

I'm stuck as to why the first/second time i tap the image it's fine, but other times, it does it's own thing.

Below is the relevant code. Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

```
        ///////////////
        //IMAGE CODE///
        ///////////////

        NSURL *imageURl = [request URL];
        NSString *imageFileExtension = [[imageURl absoluteString] pathExtension];

        NSLog(@"imageExtension is: %@", imageFileExtension);
        NSSet *supportedFileExtensions = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"bmp", @"gif", @"jpg", @"jpeg", @"png", @"psd", @"pspimage", @"tga", @"tif", @"tiff", @"yuv", @"pdf", @"raw", nil];

        if ([supportedFileExtensions containsObject:[imageFileExtension lowercaseString]]) {

            [webView stopLoading];

            //Image manager
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

            WebImageViewController *vc = [[WebImageViewController alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
            [vc release];

            NSLog(@"imageURL");

            return NO; ///PART THAT WAS LEFT OUT.

        }
```

Update right above.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in updating my app to support iOS 8, I believe I managed to leave out my "return NO;" to each of my if/else statements.

Adding that in stops the webview from loading while passing the image to my custom view controller.